# Onclick of Lead couldn't get the details of Lead in custom Module in openerp

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I'm creating a custom module and trying to convert the Lead to Opportunity.Now i'm fetching all the leads and showing like in img1. But actually i want to display like img2 and on click of any lead it should take me to simlar scrren like img3 where i can have option to converting a lead to Opportunity. My problem is on click of any lead in img1 ,there is no response.Thanks in advance.
My Code is

lead.py

```
from osv import osv
from osv import fields

class crm_lead(osv.osv):
 _name = 'crm.lead'
 _inherit = 'crm.lead'
 _description = "adding fields to crm.lead"
 _columns = {
    'nitesh_lead': fields.char('Nitesh Lead',size=64),
    'lead_source': fields.many2one('crm.lead.source','Lead Source'),
    'lead_status': fields.many2one('crm.lead.status','Lead Status')
 }
 class res_partner_title(osv.osv):
    _name = 'crm.lead.source'
    _order = 'name'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Source', required=True, size=46, translate=True)
    }
 class res_partner_title(osv.osv):
    _name = 'crm.lead.status'
    _order = 'name'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Status', required=True, size=46, translate=True)
    }
```

lead_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>

 <!-- ========================This is Form layout===============================-->
<record id="crm_case_tree_view_oppor_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">Opportunities Tree</field>
<field name="model">crm.lead</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_tree_view_oppor" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="planned_revenue" position="replace"/>
    <field name="probability" position="replace"/>
</field>
</record>


<record id="crm_case_form_view_leads_extended" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">CRM - Leads Form</field>
<field name="model">crm.lead</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads" />
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="email_from" postion="replace"/>
    <field name="contact_name" position="replace"/>
    <label for="contact_name" position="replace">
      <br/>
    </label>
    <xpath expr="//label[@for='street']" position="before">
                <field name="contact_name"/>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//label[@for='section_id']" position="before">
                <field name="lead_source"/>
                <field name="lead_status"/>
    </xpath>

    <field name="function" position="replace"/>
    <field name="partner_name" position="replace"/>
    <field name="priority" position="replace"/>
    <field name="categ_ids" position="replace"/>
    <field name="partner_id" position="replace"/>

</field>
</record>


<!-- ===========================Action layout=========================== -->
<record id="new_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
  <field name="name">Lead</field>
  <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
  <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
  <field name="view_type">form</field>
  <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
  <field name="view_id" ref="crm_case_form_view_leads_extended"/>
</record>

  <record id="show_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Lead</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="view_type">tree</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="crm_case_tree_view_oppor_extended"/>
  </record>

<!-- ===========================Menu Settings=========================== -->
<menuitem name ="Lead" id = "menu_lead" />
  <menuitem name="Leads" id="sub_menu_lead" parent="menu_lead" />
    <menuitem name="Create Lead" id="create_lead" parent="sub_menu_lead" action="new_lead"/> 
    <menuitem name="Show Lead" id="show_leads" parent="sub_menu_lead" action="show_lead"/> 
</data>
</openerp>
```

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: means you need to List view on Click on any Lead ?? Like in img2.

Comment: @Odedra Yes and onclick of any Lead in img2, i should get all details like in img3(basically i should able to convert into Opportunity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only need one menuitem to show your leads (you can create from within it).

so first the action:

```
<record id="show_lead" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Lead</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="crm_case_tree_view_oppor_extended"/>
</record>
```

and the menuitem:

```
<menuitem name="Show Lead" id="show_leads" parent="sub_menu_lead" action="show_lead"/>
```

just delete the create_lead action and menuitem

and a little hint: if you got xml errors, go to the stacktrace riiiiight before the output of the xml part (the record where the error belongs to) and you will mostly find the real error message like "can't find field *anyfield* in model *anymodel*"